# VCL components in a service scheduler

Tags: delphi, calendar, devexpress, vcl

I'm using the TcxScheduler, TcxSchedulerStorage and TIBOQuery
components with VCL form in Delphi in a system for service scheduling in a calendar.
Inside the system I manage events and employee breaks.
However in the DataNavigator property its subproperty ShowdatesContainingEventsinBold is enabled.
When the cxScheduler.DateNavigator.Visible event is called the days that have breaks created as events are marked in bold.
Is there any other way to create breaks without marking them as events?

Comment: Did you ask the component vendor?

Comment: unfortunately I do not have access to the component manufacturer's support . More if someone
power to help stay on topic liking.

Comment: If you have a licensed copy of the Devex VCL library (which includes TcxScheduler), you are entitled to use their support.  Have you not tried asking them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want. Your question is very vague.

Do you want to bold specific days in you cxScheduler

If so you can create a DateNavigator.CustomDrawDayNumber event at implement it like this :

```
procedure TForm1.cxScheduler1DateNavigatorCustomDrawDayNumber(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo: TcxSchedulerDateNavigatorDayNumberViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  if DayOfWeek(AViewInfo.Date) in [1, 7] then
    ACanvas.Font.Color := clRed;
end;
```

Comment: Here's a bit of the code I'm using.http://pastebin.com/4pusm1tj also, here's an image of the window I'm editing http://i.imgur.com/S2WJcKE.jpg to the left outlined in red are the employee's work breaks, I registered those work breaks as events, however I would not like the calendar (to the right) to highlight those events in bold, I want the calendar to ignore those specific events.